# For loop run just once

Tags: visualforce, controller, aggregate, loop

I have seven different recordtypes, but it seems that the first "for" (FOR (RecordType RType : RTypeList) loop run just once. The debug log show that the sql find 7 rows.

> 09:22:47.089 (89771210)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[11]|Aggregations:0|SELECT
>   Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Opportunity'
>   09:22:47.124 (124132161)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[11]|Rows:7

```
Public Class VTPTeam3_class {

    Public Summary[] Summaries {
        get;
        set;
    }

    Public VTPTeam3_class() {

    }

    Public void getInformation() {

        List < RecordType > RTypeList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Opportunity'];
        FOR(RecordType RType: RTypeList) {

            AggregateResult[] Results = [SELECT Account.Owner.Name accOwner, RecordType.Name oppProduct, SUM(Amount) PlanValue FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId = : RType.Id GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name, RecordType.Name];
            Summaries = new List < Summary > ();
            FOR(AggregateResult ar: Results) {
                Summaries.ADD(new Summary(ar));
            }
        }

    }

    Public Class Summary {
        Public String Ownername {
            get;
            set;
        }
        Public String Productname {
            get;
            set;
        }
        Public Double Value {
            get;
            set;
        }

        Public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
            Ownername = (String) ar.get('accOwner');
            Productname = (String) ar.get('oppProduct');
            Value = (Double) ar.get('PlanValue');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you sure about the loop running just once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is probably that you re-initilaise the `Summaries` list every time round the loop to an empty list so you end up with only 1 item in the final list.

This is probably what you want:

```
   Summaries = new List < Summary > ();
   FOR(RecordType RType: RTypeList) {
        AggregateResult[] Results = [SELECT Account.Owner.Name accOwner, RecordType.Name oppProduct, SUM(Amount) PlanValue FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId = : RType.Id GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name, RecordType.Name];
        FOR(AggregateResult ar: Results) {
            Summaries.ADD(new Summary(ar));
        }
    }
```